Impedance matrix of a GSG probe
I want to design a CPW that allows for high transmission. Therefore, my first guess was to find the impedance of a CPW for the even mode. I have decided to solve it from the ground up. I have used a python FEM solver to get the modes, however, now I'm struggling to get the characteristic impedance.
==========================
EDIT: To be more precise on the structure, I am talking about 3 conductors on a substrate as follows:

For such structure two modes are present, as below. The odd mode is referred to as the Mode 1:

==========================
From my understanding a CPW must be interpreted as a multi conductor transmission line, and for that I get an impedance matrix Z that follows the paper 1. However, I now have no clue how to interpret this. Normally we are told to design something for a 50 Ohm termination to get everything impedance matched. But now we have an impedance matrix. In this formalism the same applies, but now we simply have to match matrices instead of scalars. However, say I buy a GSG probe from 2. They show high transmission from interfacing with a coaxial cable of 50 Ohm. But what does that mean for the impedance matrix of the GSG probe?
1 F. Olyslager, A. Franchois, and D. De Zutter, “Reciprocity based transmission line equations for higher order eigenmodes in lossy waveguides,” Wave Motion, vol. 41, no. 3, pp. 229–238, Mar. 2005, doi: 10.1016/j.wavemoti.2004.04.005.
2 https://ggb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/mod67a.pdf

Please define CPW.

@TimWilliams I have added an edit in the question

I could be wrong on this, but it's likely it's an s-parameter matrix, which can describe reflections and loss in both directions:
https://ez.analog.com/ez-blogs/b/engineerzone-spotlight/posts/the-top-5-things-you-need-to-know-about-rf-matching-networks

USUALLY for a CPW transmission line all conductors are grounded with the exception of the signal conductor. And if there are  multiple modes the dimensions are chosen so that only one mode is propagating at the frequencies of interest. When this is the case the higher-order modes are irrelevant.
I don't know what is in the paper OP referenced (and it's not one easily viewed on the web) so I don't know what matrix they are talking about.
